# React Autocomplete matching highlighted word

Tags: reactjs

I have autocompleted features. when I search for something we will get the data accordingly. But I want to add one more feature like when we search data will come as well as whatever I typed in the search box that character should be highlighted in yellow color.

```
Here is the piece of code I have written.
```

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [names, setnames] = useState([{
  "name": "Barbara-anne"
}, {
  "name": "Debi"
}, {
  "name": "Cara"
}, {
  "name": "Cristin"
}, {
  "name": "Jocelyne"
}, {
  "name": "Joellyn"
}, {
  "name": "Elmo"
}, {
  "name": "Ivette"
}, {
  "name": "Lea"
}, {
  "name": "Michel"
}, {
  "name": "Leigha"
}, {
  "name": "Titus"
}, {
  "name": "Nollie"
}, {
  "name": "Celle"
}, {
  "name": "Thea"
}, {
  "name": "Brynn"
}, {
  "name": "Sloane"
}, {
  "name": "Margalo"
}, {
  "name": "Genevieve"
}, {
  "name": "Niel"
}, {
  "name": "Heddi"
}, {
  "name": "Gregg"
}, {
  "name": "Eduard"
}, {
  "name": "Kizzee"
}, {
  "name": "Truman"
}, {
  "name": "Merill"
}, {
  "name": "Lindie"
}, {
  "name": "Vasily"
}, {
  "name": "Averil"
}, {
  "name": "Golda"
}, {
  "name": "Zorine"
}, {
  "name": "Odele"
}, {
  "name": "Amalie"
}, {
  "name": "Ilsa"
}, {
  "name": "Pepillo"
}, {
  "name": "Hewe"
}, {
  "name": "Byrann"
}, {
  "name": "Alford"
}, {
  "name": "Lanny"
}, {
  "name": "Kristina"
}, {
  "name": "Mar"
}, {
  "name": "Vittoria"
}, {
  "name": "Winslow"
}, {
  "name": "Ashlan"
}, {
  "name": "Gayelord"
}])
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')
  const filteredName=names.filter((val)=>{
            if(searchTerm ===""){
                return val;
            }else if(val.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())){
                return val;
            }
        });
  const renderStatementResult = searchTerm && searchTerm.length > 0;
  return (
    <>
          <div className="srchField">
            <label for="statement">Statement Name</label>
            <div className="valueField">
              <input type="text" name="fileName" id="statement" data-validate="true" placeholder="Type Name" onChange={event => {setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}}/>
                {
                  renderStatementResult ? <ul className="lookup-results">
                  {filteredName.map((value)=>(<li key={value.name}>{value.name}</li>))}
                </ul> : null
                }
            </div>
          </div>
            
        </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

refer this image [image]

1. Can anyone have an idea of how to match the highlighted text. I want to highlight all s in yellow color

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
             {filteredName.map((value)=>(<li key={value.name}>{
              
              value.name.split('').map((char) => {
                if (searchTerm.toLowerCase().split('').includes(char.toLowerCase())) {
                  return <span style={{ color: 'yellow' }}>{char}</span>;
                } else {
                  return <span>{char}</span>;
                }
              })
              
              }</li>))}
```

Comment: I tested your code. one problem i found. Let's say i am searching 'B' related name.
I got 
 Barbara-anne
 Debi
 Brynn
 Byrann
But in 'Debi' name i can't find the heighlighted

Comment: You should use either toLowerCase or toUpperCase

Comment: Just updated my answer adding toLowerCase

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/elated-chandrasekhar-ggoi1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: follow sandbox link. problem is "Debi prasad Debi" is there. when i search "Debi" , Debi is highlighted it's good but as well as in "prasad" 'd' also highlighted. only matches should be highlighted.

Comment: I can't see what you mean.. The code is working

Answer (score 0):

Replace your map function with

```
filteredName.map((value) => {
                let string = value.name.substr(
                  0,
                  value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
                );
                let endString = value.name.substr(
                  value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) +
                    searchTerm.length
                );
                let highlightedText = value.name.substr(
                  value.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()),
                  searchTerm.length
                );
                return (
                  <li key={value.name}>
                    {string}
                    <span style={{ "background-color": "#FFFF00" }}>
                      {highlightedText}
                    </span>
                    {endString}
                  </li>
                );
              })
```

The first line( let string =...) extracts the part of string which comes before the part that should be highlighted, and the next line extracts the part after the highlight. The search term itself is kept in a span tag which is styled to highlight.

The above snippet only highlights the first occurrence of the search term, so if the search term is 's' and one of the names is 'Samson', only the first 's' would be highlighted. If you want to highlight all occurrences, then you can use regular expressions to find out the indices of all occurrences and loop across the indices, constructing your li tag along the way.

A working sandbox can be found at https://codesandbox.io/embed/elated-chandrasekhar-ggoi1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: It works, but if the search character is beginning . e.g; "B"  i am searching then it not working. Barbara-anne and Bdebi also coming. look at the "Bdebi".
Again when i press 'i' after 'B' then output is coming like: Biebi->Bi is inside span tag

Comment: Thanks for the tip off. That was happening because my earlier answer didn't account for different casing. Updated it to accommodate the same.

Comment: But problem is to check the sandbox I have modified.
let's say "Debi prasad Debi" is there and when we search Debi the first one is only highlighting not the second one. there are two places Debi is there.
so both should be highlighted. How to use regular expression