# How can we access local JSON file data in react class component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js

I am trying to build a movies/series search app in nextjs react based class component and I am getting the content of json after importing file with help of simple console and map function like this below

```
<div>
    {Appletv.shows.map((appletitle, index) => {
        return <h1>{appletitle.Title}</h1>;
    })}
</div>
```

but I am not getting how can I put that map data in state and after typing movie name in input box how can I show that in UI
here is my component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import Appletv from "../appletv.json";
export default class example extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            movies :''
        }
    }
    handMoviesChange =(event) =>{
        this.setState({
            movies:event.target.value
    })
    }
    handleSubmit =event =>{
      console.log(movies)
      .event.preventDefault()
    }
  render() {
    console.table(Appletv.shows);

    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <label className={styles.label}>Movies</label>
            <input
              id="name"
              className={styles.input}
              type="checkbox"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <label className={styles.label}>Series</label>
            <input id="name" className={styles.input} type="checkbox" />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <input
              className={styles.input}
              id="search"
              type="input"
              required
              placeholder="Please enter title"
             value={this.state.movies}
             onChange={this.handMoviesChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <label className={styles.label} for="genre">
              Choose Genre
            </label>
            <select name="genre" id="genre">
              <option value="scifi">SCIFI</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <input id="name" type="input" placeholder="Season Input" />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <label className={styles.label}>Netflix</label>
            <input className={styles.input} id="name" type="checkbox" />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <label className={styles.label}>Amazon Prime</label>
            <input className={styles.input} id="name" type="checkbox" />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.row}>
            <label className={styles.label}>Apple TV+</label>
            <input
              className={styles.input}
              id="name"
              type="checkbox"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button
            className={styles.button}
            type="submit" /* onClick={handleSubmit} */
          >
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
        <div>
          {Appletv.shows.map((appletitle, index) => {
            return <h1>{appletitle.Title}</h1>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

can anyone explain  what triggers i need  and how to handle the response

Comment: What state are you trying to save the imported `Appletv` JSON data into? It's static data, it probably doesn't need to be in state anyway? Can you clarify your additional question about the input? Which input, what do you want to happen when user interacts, etc...

Comment: i just want to fetch that data and then after typing name I want to show that movie or series in UI

Comment: I see. Can you update your question to include fetching data and explain what triggers it and how you handle the response?

Comment: So from what I understand, you already have the movies data available, but you want to set a list of movie/show names alone to the state so that you can display them on the UI when searched, right?

Comment: yes Rao correct

Comment: Are trying to filter the `shows` by the input value. `Appletv.shows.filter(x => x.title === this.state.movies).map(........`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward method to achieve this would be as follows:

```
let showsArray=[];
for(let show of Appletv.shows){
   showsArray.push(show.title);
}
this.setState(showsArray);
```

This should initialise your state to a list of movie/show titles.

You can use Array.prototype.map for the same as well.

Comment: in the handlesubmit

Comment: What do you mean? Please elaborate.

Comment: i did this in handleSubmit =event =>{
      console.log(movies)
      .event.preventDefault()
      let showsArray=[];
for(let show of Appletv.shows){
   showsArray.push(show.title);
}
this.setState(showsArray);
    } but still unable to to see results

Comment: Did you trigger the submit handler?

Comment: i already did in form tag

Comment: now i did this thing  handleSubmit =event =>{
      event.preventDefault()
      let showsArray=[];
for(let show of Appletv.shows){
   showsArray.push(show.Title);
}
this.setState(showsArray);
console.log(showsArray)
    } and after clicking submit i am getting data in console

Comment: okay, so can you please describe what the problem is right now? What is the desired behaviour and what is the behaviour you are getting now?

Comment: working fine but i need to do something like this now  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let newFilteredShows = [];

    /**
     * TODO: In this method you should filter the list of all shows (Appletv.shows)
     *  and put all matching shows in this.state.filteredShows.
     */
    

    for (let show of Appletv.shows) {
      newFilteredShows.push(show.Title);
    }
    this.setState({ filteredShows: newFilteredShows });
  }

Comment: The posted question is only about extracting the data and putting it into a list. In order to ensure information and answers are focussed and easily searchable, please update the question or create a separate one entirely for help on that matter.

Comment: ok bro but can you give me some hints for this todo please?

Comment: You can try referring to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380064/react-autocomplete-matching-highlighted-word/67380882?noredirect=1#comment119103461_67380882 . The code snippet in that question might be useful.